# MariaDB clashing with MySQL on Travis-CI

Tags: continuous-integration, mariadb, travis-ci

I have a test suite that runs on Travis-CI and requires MariaDB (but it breaks on MySQL). The pre-test scripts call the `mysql` command, but run commands against MariaDB, as the command is the same for both.

```
echo "CREATE DATABASE test1" | mysql -u travis
```

The tests on worker v2.5.0 were passing just fine (https://travis-ci.org/stems/join-monster/jobs/256751422). However, the tests started running on a later version of the worker v2.9.3 and failing without any changes to the code (https://travis-ci.org/stems/join-monster/jobs/260001701). According to the system build information, this new version seems to be installing MySQL in addition to MariaDB. Now when I run my `mysql` command, it's running against MySQL instead of MariaDB and breaking the build.

I need either:

1. to go back to a previous version of the worker (can't find any info on how to do this in the Travis docs.
2. to specify that I want to run commands and connect to MariaDB, NOT MySQL.
3. to tell Travis to not install MySQL to avoid the clashing

Any of these solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling mysql before installing MariaDB?

Comment: Couldn't find a way to hook into the build process at that point. The `addons` field in the `.travis.yml`, where I specify that I want MariaDB, gets applied before the `before_script` field, where the user can write arbitrary shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by switching the Ubuntu version back to 12 rather than 14, which had become the new default.

In the `.travis.yml`

```
dist: precise
```